# Why am I getting a Nixpacks error on Railway?

Tags: git, github, deployment, hosting, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my MEAN stack backend on Railway from GitHub repo, but I get a Nixpacks error which looks like this:
"=============="
Using Nixpacks
"=============="
context: ed2947ad0e8ecf616927e0060d4c0270
Nixpacks build failed

Nixpacks was unable to generate a build plan for this app.
Please check the documentation for supported languages: https://nixpacks.com

The contents of the app directory are:

README.md                                                                                                                   It gives me this https://nixpacks.com link and when I go there it shows me some commands, first one is to install nixpacks which gives me an error when I try. Does someone know why do I need the Nixpacks and why can't I install it? Or if you know a good tutorial on youtube please give me a link, watched some videos but they didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem with a project, it seems to be that you need to configure Railway Settings and specify the route where the project actually is, cause Railway has a default one.

If you don't have the project in root, you need to specify it. I don't know if you already solved it but I wanted to help :)

Here is where you should specify the route:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a Django application hitting this exact error and the solution for me was to ensure my `requirements.txt` was setup - classic error!